# Are these operators and the fourier transform compact?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

I do not want a proof but rather an explanation.

I just read that $T_k:L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ 
such that $(T_kf)(s) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} k(s,t)f(t) dt $ is compact. (in this case: $k \in L^2$)

Does this implfy that $T_k:C(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C(\mathbb{R})$  with $(T_kf)(s) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} k(s,t)f(t) dt $ is compact?

And am I getting this right: Does the first one imply, that things like the fourier transform are compact?

Comment: Fourier transform on $L^2$ is a unitary, so not compact.

Comment: alright, but in that case: Does this not somehow contradict the theorem that I quoted at the beginning?

Comment: No, because $k \notin L^2$ for the Fourier transform. (When $k \in L^2$ does your theorem say Hilbert-Schimidt or just compact?)

Comment: just compact...alright, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fourier transform is not compact on any function space that contains [Hermite functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions), because those functions form an infinite family of eigenfunctions with unimodular eigenvalues. This applies to both $L^2(\mathbb R)$ and $C(\mathbb R)$ (on the latter, the Fourier transform does not behave well anyway: the transform of a continuous function, even if it vanishes at infinity, can be a distribution that's not a function).

For general $k\in L^2$ the formula $(T_kf)(s) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} k(s,t)f(t) dt$ does not define an operator on $C(\mathbb R)$. For one thing, the integral may fail to converge; for another, $T_kf$ need not be continuous.